# Jax-b and Jackson marshalling for unspecified amount of elements?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, jackson, resteasy

In a project I am working on with restEASY I am pulling people from a database. One of the requested features is allowing the user to specify fields they would like in the url via query parameters. Because of this the number of fields I would like to return when marshalling to xml or json won't be known until runtime. Is there a way to get jax-b and jackson to ignore a field at runtime?

Another thought I had was maintaining an collection of type Field that would essentially be a key value pair, but I would like to control the root element name.

What I am looking for in the output is something like

```
<person>
    <FirstName>Bob</FirstName>
    <LastName>Smith</LastName>
    <id>12345</id>
</person>
```

There could be up to 50 of those fields and I don't want to show a bunch of empty fields. I want to only show what the user requests. With my collection of fields (basically a marked up key value pair) I could do this.

```
<person>
    <field>
        <name>FirstName</name>
        <value>Bob</value>
    </field>
    <field>
        <name>LastName</name>
        <value>Smith</value
    </field>
    <field>
        <name>id</name>
        <value>1234</value>
    </field>
</field>
```

So to summarize I either want to be able to ignore fields that have xml markup based on a condition during runtime, or I want to be able to set XMLRootElement name's programatically.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could `null` out all fields not needed and make sure your xml serialization does not include null values (I think this is default).

Comment: Well I feel stupid now, thanks a lot you just saved me a lot of work.